# Autocomplete Countries List using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places

I have the following code which I've been manipulating for a while, but I simply can't get it to return results..

```
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
            };
            var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class = "row">
        <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
    </div>
</body>
```

Using the above code i am able to get the cities list for a specific Country. But my requirement is I need to get the Countries list alone.

If the options is not passed then all the Places are returned as Result.

Is there any way to filter the countries alone ??? Please help me if you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this point, you can't as there is no 'country' [place type](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types). Regions will autocomplete countries though (but not countries alone).

```
    var options = {
        types: ['(regions)']
    };
```

[Get only countries to autocomplete from Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918431/get-only-countries-to-autocomplete-from-google-maps-api) offers some alternative solutions. Here's an example of regions alone: http://plnkr.co/edit/QjPEczt6AosghVP8EHNV

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I think i need to try the alternative solutions as you mentioned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can anyone provide me any code snippet or any ideas using alternative solutions to retrieve the countries list?Please help