# i need to develope autoComplete for country,state and city in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

autoComplete for country,state and city.after entering country name it should load all countries names with that name and for state it should load state autocomplete 
based on the selected country .and similarly city dropdown should populate based on state selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using plain AngularJS or angular-material design

Comment: i am using plain AngularJs

Comment: then ngAutoComplete is the way to do it.
http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/

Comment: But i need to develope state auto complete based on country selected and city based on state name selected

Comment: How can i load only country names in autoComplete instead of full details with address @Rakeschand

Answer (score 0):

1. Initially Call country lookup.
2. Once you select the Country pass the country Id and  call State lookup
3. Similarly after you select state pass the state Id and call City Lookup

   ```
   <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state.abbreviation as state.name for state in states | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)">
   ```

Link for Auto Complete [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pFsPx0lTM7OZVwF97m1l?p=preview)

Comment: tip: check out ES6s Promise for how you can chain these calls :) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having dependencies. Based on first selection you can make a call for second drop down list and so on. You can use [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) but Google only offers two type collections: '(cities)'and '(regions)'

go through:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918431/get-only-countries-to-autocomplete-from-google-maps-api)

Comment: thanks.But this is a dropdown select.i require autoComplete.

Comment: hope this may be useful for you 

http://plnkr.co/edit/GE34ojss9xMGm0024FvM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.but the above link showing full address in autoComplete.i need only country,state and city names in dropdowns.

Comment: I tried to get your scenario but I didnt figure out a way to get only countries, but for cities there is option cities. for countries there is option country but it is not working. you can go through [this](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types). In js file you need to give options.

Comment: is there any other way of getting country,state and city names in autoComplete instead of google  places api ?

Comment: Once check this @Arunkumar [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12918624/6396473)  

and also [Link2](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector)