# Get only country result using react places auto complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

React places autocomplete have a `searchOption` prop inside that we can give `types` array there we can specify whether we want cities, address, regions locality. Now what I need is to set the types array so i can only get countries as the autocomplete result

Types option accept address, (cities), (regions) but i can't find a way for country. https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete

[image]

I am getting all the info from maps docs but no help. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

I have tried some solutions but not working.
My first time question so i am sorry if i am not asking a good question

Comment: I have asked a similar question. Can  you please provide a bit more information

Comment: Added a bit more information

Comment: I am doing the same thing and asked the same question so it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass an option `'country'` in the type array. Refer to this document on google maps places API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3

Edit : Google doesn't provide any direct support to list only country in autocomplete API. refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145499/4613544.

Comment: yes but that doesn't work. It says if we provide (regions) then it will give the result in locality, sublocality, postal_code, country etc accordingly. But i only want the country result. I have tried different combinations but no luck

Comment: to get the results as only country names pass a single argument in type.


`types:['country']`

Comment: I just find out the issues and the sad part is google doesn't provide any particular fix for this. Although, I find a solution from this guy, and is working perfectly for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145499/4613544