# Restrict Google Places to country in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am using GooglePlaces to get places

**myController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/connexionFR")
public String displayLoginPageFR(Model model) {
... 
client = new GooglePlaces("MY_KEY_GOOGLE");
...
return "/FR/MDB_VTC.html";
}


@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<String> doAutoComplete(@RequestParam("q") final String input) {       
    List<String> proposition = new ArrayList<>(); 
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
    List<Prediction> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions(input);
    for(Prediction p : predictions) {
        proposition.add(p.getDescription());            
    }
    
    strings = getStrings(input, proposition) ; 
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String resp = "";

    try {
        resp = mapper.writeValueAsString(strings);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**myHTML.html**

```
...
<input type="text" name="search" id="searchBox" style="width: 560px; margin: auto;" />
...

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "http://localhost:8092/search",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {
                        q : request.term
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                        //alert(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength : 1
        });
    });
</script>
...
```

I am only getting US result and i want to get other countries result.

Comment: I assume you are using [google-places-api-java](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java). Please, be aware that [Google Places autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results) will only return up to five results: is it possible that you are looking for places that can be found in US? Perhaps is related with the problem. In addition, have you tried providing the country/ies you want to obtain results for to the API? You can do that providing the `components` param, something like: see next comment

Comment: `List<Prediction> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions(input,Param.name("components").value("country:fr"))`. You can provide a list of countries as well: `List<Prediction> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions(input,Param.name("components").value("country:fr|country:dz"))`

Comment: checkout the answer by wmock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918431/get-only-countries-to-autocomplete-from-google-maps-api

Comment: @jccampanero hello i've tested your solution and it is working can you please write an answer that  i can validate

Comment: Thank you very much @YagamiLight. I wrote an answer. I am very happy to hear that you managed to solve the problem and that the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments provided in the question, probably are using the [google-places-api-java](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java) library.

As described in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results), please, be aware that Google Places autocomplete will only return up to five results: perhaps you are looking for places that can be found in US and the API is returning them in first place, it can be related to the problem.

In addition, please, try providing the country or countries you want to obtain results for to the API. You can do that using the `components` param, something like:

```java
List<Prediction> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions(
  input,Param.name("components").value("country:fr")
);
```

You can provide a list of countries as well:

```java
List<Prediction> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions(
  input,Param.name("components").value("country:fr|country:dz")
);
```