# How to get the AutoComplete country list and country code list from Google places?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to run the following API call.n I am following the API DOC here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#types

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?
types=regions:country
&input=sri
&key=API_KEY
&language=en
```

But I am always getting the following output.

```
{
    "predictions": [],
    "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? It is not possible to autocomplete the country list with codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only countries to autocomplete from Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918431/get-only-countries-to-autocomplete-from-google-maps-api)

Comment: @geocodezip: It is not. The question you have pointed out is 9 years old, last answer is 6 years old . Technology evolves.

Answer (score 0):

In your request, `type=regions:country` is not valid. You can use `type=(regions)` like the docs specify:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#types

This is as close as you can get to only countries.

A request like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?types=(regions)&input=sri&key=API_KEY&language=en` will return Sri Lanka as first prediction. You could further filter your predictions by looking for only ones with "country" in the "types" field of the response.